# Gensim - iterating over multiple documents

Tags: gensim

I'm trying to the Q6 recipe shown [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ) but my corpus keep getting returned as [] even though I have checked and it does seem to be reading the document correctly.

So my code is:

```
def iter_documents(top_directory):
    """Iterate over all documents, yielding a document (=list of utf8 tokens) at a time."""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
        for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.txt'), files):
            document = open(os.path.join(root, file)).read() # read the entire document, as one big string
            yield utils.tokenize(document, lower=True) # or whatever tokenization suits you
class MyCorpus(object):
    # Used to create the object
    def __init__(self, top_dir):
        self.top_dir = top_dir
        self.dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(iter_documents(top_dir))
        self.dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=1, keep_n=30000) # check API docs for pruning params
# Used if you ever need to iterate through the values
def __iter__(self):
    for tokens in iter_documents(self.top_dir):
        yield self.dictionary.doc2bow(tokens)
```

and the text file I'm using to test is [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/mycorpus.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Change line 12 to this: `self.dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=0, no_above=1,keep_n=30000)`

Because I only have 1 document to start with it's being filtered out.
See [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_extremes)